# How can I move the turtle every few seconds without using time.sleep()?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a Tetris like game, with turtle.

When the block goes down, I use time.sleep() to make it wait for a few seconds before it goes down. But, the time.sleep() make the ENTIRE code stop, I want only the defintion to stop:

```
def moveDown():
    time.sleep(2)
    turtle(sety(100)
    time.sleep(2)
    turtle.sety(0)
    time.sleep(2)
    turtle.sety(-100)
    time.sleep(2)
    turtle.sety(-200)
    setBlock()
```

I don't want the ENTIRE code to stop, because the player needs to use the left and right keys to navigate around the screen. So, how would I achieve this? Sorry if this was very rambley and muddled.

Comment: What you'd want to do in a case like this is only move the block after a certain amount of time has passed. You can do that by saving the initial time, then checking the current time against the initial time until enough time has passed. At least, that's a simple way to do it - there are probably other, better ways.

Comment: What you want is to use `turtle.ontimer` https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html?highlight=timer#turtle.ontimer  (also you should clarify your title and add `turtle` to tags.

Answer (score 1):

What is going on with time.sleep() is that it is what is known as a "blocking call" meaning that when it is called, your process will not proceed until it is done. You need to have another thread/process to run in the background to cause it to move.
Something like this:

```
def moveDown():
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor())
    if moveable:
        screen.ontimer(moveDown, 2000) #ms
```

Then elsewhere in your code:

```
...
    moveable=True
    moveDown()
...
```

Then stop it with:

```
...
    moveable=False
...
```

That is a very simplistic example (based off the python.org example)

Answer (score 0):

time.clock() can report the number of seconds since it has started so you can check against it to see if you will allow the user to input commands for a certain interval once it is on the bottom

```
import time
junk = time.clock()
pause_at_bottom = 0.5
## code till it hits the bottom
at_bottom = time.clock()
while time.clock() < (at_bottom + pause_at_bottom):
    ## code to run while at the bottom
## code to run once time has elapsed at bottom
```